# How to Create/Update/Delete a user for multiple companies with only one Persist() action of graph?

Tags: acumatica, persist

I have 5 companies and want to create/update/delete a `User` for companies was selected in `Companies` grid with checkbox.
The problem is, when I check 3 companies (`company2`, `company3`, `company5`) to create a `User` for them and press button `Save` then `Persist()` method just create with the last checked company (`company5`).
I use delegate method and `PXLoginScope` to login for every company inside the `Persist()` method.

```
public class AccessUsers_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AccessUsers>
{
    public PXSelect<Company> Companies;

    public delegate void PersistDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        foreach (Company company in Companies.Cache.Inserted)
        {
            CompanyExt ordExt = PXCache<Company>.GetExtension<CompanyExt>(company);
            if ((bool)ordExt.UsrSelected)
            {
                using (PXLoginScope ls = new PXLoginScope(PXAccess.GetUserName() + "@" + company.CompanyKey))
                {
                    AccessUsers ac = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AccessUsers>();
                    ac.Caches = Base.Caches;
                    ac.Actions.PressSave();

                    if (ls != null)
                    {
                        ((IDisposable)ls).Dispose();
                        PXDatabase.ResetCredentials();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good you posted your current approach, but also describe the exact problem in the question.

Comment: thank theLearner, I was updated my question.